# Is Running node js file with arguments more than once allowed?

Tags: node.js

Can I run one node js file two times with arguments passed on in the command line. say the file is main.js, Can I do `node main.js 1` and `node main.js 2` in two separate lines to run two files in separate threads.

Comment: Yes! you can! each one will have a process/thread identifiable through a pid and executing concurrently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. However if you want to do this on the same command prompt window, you must background the first one:

```
> node main.js 1 &
> node main.js 2
```

I don't recommend this though unless you want to go into the task manager to kill the first one, or you're proficient enough to get its pid and `kill` it.

#### Protip

Running node.js files with the extension is optional. You can simply do this:

```
> node main 1
```